# Perl file descriptor streaming

Tags: perl, io

I am trying to modify this Perl code to do what I need. Right now it reads data from a file descriptor and once 8000 bytes are buffered it completes and moved on to write them into a file.

I am trying to get it to continue to read every 8000 bytes from that stream and only stop when the script is killed or X numbers of cycles go by.
So it would keep adding 8000 bytes every time they are buffered or just write data to the file every X number of seconds.

I am not familiar with streams and have not written in perl, cant find any documentation that i could apply to this, although I think the solution is faily straigh forward. I will appreciate the help, will post any new updates

```
 use warnings;
 use strict;

 use IO::Handle;

 $| = 1; 
 my $buffer = undef;
 my $result = undef;
 my $AUDIO_FD = 3;   
 my $audio_fh = new IO::Handle;
 $audio_fh->fdopen( $AUDIO_FD, "r" );         


 my $bytes_read = $audio_fh->read( $buffer, 8000 );
 $audio_fh->close();


 my $fh;
 open( $fh, ">/tmp/rawdata.txt" );
 print $fh $buffer;
 close( $fh );
```

Comment: I would look at the documentation https://perldoc.perl.org/IO/Handle.html . For the read method, you can specify an offset " $io->read ( BUF, LEN, [OFFSET] )" . You should be able to wrap a loop around this

Comment: @hoffmeister you don't need the offset at all. `read` will take the next 8000 bytes from where it left off.

Comment: @simbabque  The `OFFSET` is where the new read is written in the target string (`BUF`). Otherwise it wlll rewrite what's there from the previous read.

Comment: (1) Why `IO::Handle`?  Just [open](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) the file (2) Use [read](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/read.html) in a loop (3) Set up [alarm](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/alarm.html) to interrupt reading, so to write, every X cycles. See the link and [Signals in perlipc](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html#Signals) for how to recover after the signal. For better granularity than a second use `ualarm` from [Time::HiRes](https://perldoc.perl.org/Time/HiRes.html) (4) Set up signal handlers and `END` block to ensure it's written on termination ...

Comment: ... and post questions for problems once you get it going.  (Right now  you are asking for a fairly complex program to be simply delivered, with "_I ... have not written in perl_")

Comment: Forgot to write for (3) above: The whole thing needs to be in a loop (`while (1)` style) so to return to reading after the `alarm` takes you out of there.

Comment: So far i found that data is pulled only when the connection is closed. In other words after $audio_fh->close(); is executed.  For this reason, while loop does nothing.

Comment: Re "_data is pulled only when the connection is closed_" -- that would not make any sense and would contradict what you are trying to do.  If you add a print of `$buffer` right after `read` it should print the last 8kB of data, just read.  And you have to keep reading those chunks so you must have a loop of some sort.  But note that `read` is buffered; if you really needed unbuffered reading then use `sysread` (but you probably don't).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This approach will not allow reading from file continuously, however, I was able to get constant data stream from same file descriptor using bash cp command

Comment: At this point I am not sure what you mean by "_streaming_".  Normally a file is read line by line (and then this is buffered, too), or you can request a specific number of bytes/chars to be read with `read` (which is buffered, too) -- or with `sysread`, which is unbuffered.  The external `cp` command just copies the whole file over, I don't see how to consider that "_streaming_".

Comment: It is considered streaming because original file continuously grows with new data, so it has to be ready continuously